# Android button layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have recently coded my button to be aligned to the right of the screen and it seems to not want to work. 
I have also checked to see if my parent layout is set to cover the whole width of the screen and it is.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Vertical Layout - For the layout of the newSheetLayout.
    newSheetLayoutV = new LinearLayout(this);
    newSheetLayoutV.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    //Horizontal layout - nested in Vertical layout. Used for the next, back and save buttons.
    newSheetButtonLayoutH = new LinearLayout(this);
    newSheetButtonLayoutH.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

  //Vertical Layout - For the layout of the newSheetLayout.
    dataShowV = new LinearLayout(this);
    dataShowV.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    //Horizontal layout - nested in the dataShow V. Used for the data entry objects.
    dataShowH = new LinearLayout(this);
    dataShowH.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    //Next button.
    nextButton = new Button(this);
    nextButton.setText("NEXT >");
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(nextListener);

    //Back button.
    backButton = new Button(this);
    backButton.setText("< BACK");
    backButton.setOnClickListener(backListener);
    backButton.setEnabled(false);

    //Save button.
    saveButton = new Button(this);
    saveButton.setText("Save");
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(saveListener);
    saveButton.setEnabled(false);

    //Addition of the buttons to the button view in order that needs to be seen.
    newSheetButtonLayoutH.addView(backButton);
    newSheetButtonLayoutH.addView(nextButton);
    newSheetButtonLayoutH.addView(saveButton);

    //Layout Param's for the buttons.
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    newSheetButtonLayoutH.setLayoutParams(params); 

    //Set save to anchor right.
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams saveButtonParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    saveButtonParam.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    saveButton.setLayoutParams(saveButtonParam);

    //Add all the layout Views to the main layout view.
    newSheetLayoutV.addView(dataShowV);
    newSheetLayoutV.addView(newSheetButtonLayoutH);
    newSheetLayoutV.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

    setContentView(newSheetLayoutV);
}
```

If it is something simple and I'm very blind to the solution, I will punish myself accordingly.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Set setLayoutGravity to Right.

Comment: you got it? check edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
saveButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.RIGHT);
```

if you are using xml and your need is not to do it in dynamic way then do

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

Edit:
i think this is what you want

[image]

```
LinearLayout newSheetLayoutV,dataShowV,dataShowH,newSheetButtonLayoutH,newlayout;
    Button nextButton,backButton,saveButton;
    //RelativeLayout ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        newSheetLayoutV = new LinearLayout(this);
        newSheetLayoutV.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        //Horizontal layout - nested in Vertical layout. Used for the next, back and save buttons.
        newSheetButtonLayoutH = new LinearLayout(this);
        newSheetButtonLayoutH.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        newlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        newlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        newlayout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        newlayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //newSheetButtonLayoutH = new RelativeLayout(this);


      //Vertical Layout - For the layout of the newSheetLayout.
        dataShowV = new LinearLayout(this);
        dataShowV.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        //Horizontal layout - nested in the dataShow V. Used for the data entry objects.
        dataShowH = new LinearLayout(this);
        dataShowH.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        //Next button.
        nextButton = new Button(this);
        nextButton.setText("NEXT >");
        //nextButton.setOnClickListener(nextListener);

        //Back button.
        backButton = new Button(this);
        backButton.setText("< BACK");
        //backButton.setOnClickListener(backListener);
        backButton.setEnabled(false);

        //Save button.
        saveButton = new Button(this);
        saveButton.setText("Save");
        //saveButton.setOnClickListener(saveListener);
        saveButton.setEnabled(false);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams saveButtonParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //saveButtonParam.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        saveButton.setLayoutParams(saveButtonParam);
        //Addition of the buttons to the button view in order that needs to be seen.

        newSheetButtonLayoutH.addView(backButton);

        newSheetButtonLayoutH.addView(nextButton);
        newlayout.addView(saveButton);
        newSheetButtonLayoutH.addView(newlayout);

        //Layout Param's for the buttons.
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        newSheetButtonLayoutH.setLayoutParams(params); 

        //Set save to anchor right.


        //Add all the layout Views to the main layout view.
        newSheetLayoutV.addView(dataShowV);
        newSheetLayoutV.addView(newSheetButtonLayoutH);
        newSheetLayoutV.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

        setContentView(newSheetLayoutV);

    }
```

Comment: This worked but it only stretched the button to the right. It is also set to wrap_content so that should have worked. I will tinker a little bit with this after I have checked with the other answers.

Comment: i think you should go step by step in coding first set `LayoutParams` to your `Layout` then set `Layout` to your `Button` and then add your `Button` in `Layout`.

Comment: OK I will give it a go. I guess it would not hurt to try.

Comment: Ha-ha the re-code broke it again... I am not sure why this is happening it should be pulled to the right and there should be nothing stopping it...

Comment: what is `newSheetButtonLayoutH` ? if possible paste full code.

Comment: yea I am not I am sure you could tell from the part of code that was shown. I will append it to the question

Comment: check edited answer tell whether you want your output to look like that?

Comment: He-he, no close. I need it on the Right hand side of that view, away from the other buttons.

Comment: That's it :D Thanks for your dedication! I'll give the code a go now.

Comment: OK I see what you have done, so I have to create a new layout to get it to align to the right?

Comment: i will recommend you to use xml for designing instead of dynamically creating your view, because using xml gives you better efficiency.

Comment: Better efficiency at expense of control? Besides I have never done XML, its not the hardest thing to learn as I have learned a bit of it, but I find programming the code for the button etc in Java easier as that is what I learned.

Comment: control? when you design using code then your app have to do extra efforts to first create all the controls and render them, also your code looks very messy because you combine design and logic in one file. When you use `XML` for design you keep both things on separate bench so that you can work with them easily and separately. you doesn't have to take care of creating view it just uses XML to do that. Using `XML` for designing is a very easy and simple thing than coding for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `layout_gravity` of `LinearLayout` instead of your `Button`.

Comment: This will not work as the gravity of the layout has been set to fill parent for the width field. Besides there are two other buttons in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving RelativeLayout params

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel_lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rel_lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    rel_lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);      
    btn.setLayoutParams(rel_lp);
```

Comment: This wont work as its a linearLayout and the two layouts are not compatible. The result will be an exception due to the parent layout being linearLayout.